# PyQT5 Unable to run qtdemo.py : ValueError: PyCapsule

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyqt5, qt5

I have installed `sip-4.19.13` and `PyQt5_gpl-5.11.3` (by specifiying `./configure.py --sip <path>`) on a Raspberry PI 3 from sources (no packages found with apt or pip).

However, I can't manage to run `qtdemo.py` in the examples folder:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name
```

How can I fix it? I've googled it but not found any solutions...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with installed `PyQt5_gpl-5.12`,

> from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *  ValueError: PyCapsule_GetPointer called with incorrect name,

then `pip uninstall PyQt5` and `pip install -i https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple pyqt5==5.10.1`